# How to get data from my axios request without using a setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am having a problem, I believe many of you have faced it somehow, so I am using `axios` to get my data :

```
 let data = axios.get(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/taskExecution?&search=&page=1&size=8"
  ).then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log("LOADING");
    } else {
      return response.data;
    }
  });
  let tasks = [];

  data.then(response => {
    tasks = response;
  });

  console.log(tasks);

  return tasks;
```

Something like this, response data returns array of 8 items, but `tasks` is still empty which is normal because the `axios` request takes some time, I can use setTimeout for 100ms and inside it, I put `console.log(tasks);` and it will work but is not a proper solution, because what if the server takes 5s to returns the data?

This code is in my reducer, so I have to get my `tasks` and return them so I can display them, and show a loader when the request is executed.

This is my reducer :

```
import update from "immutability-helper";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function getTasksReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_TASKS":
      let data = Axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/taskExecution?&search=&page=1&size=8"
      ).then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log("LOADING");
        } else {
          return response.data;
        }
      });
      let tasks = [];

      data.then(response => {
        tasks = response;
      });

      console.log(tasks);

      return tasks;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I need some help in this code and also in the conception of it, I mean where should I change my loader state and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can spent some time in understanding Promises and async/awiat

For eg: if you do this, your console will have all tasks listed.

```
 data.then(response => {
   tasks = response;
   console.log(tasks);
 });
```

Reason for that is the function you are passing to `.then` function of a promise is not executed immediately, its executed once a Promise is resolved(In your case after finishing execution of the http request.)

To get a more line by line execution feel you can use async/await

```
  let tasks = await Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/taskExecution?&search=&page=1&size=8")
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
         console.log("LOADING");
      } else {
         return response.data;
      }
    });
    console.log(tasks);
    return tasks;
```

The catch is that you can use await only inside an async function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: But how is that is going to solve my problem, to use await I need to put it inside an async method, so my tasks are declared inside the async method, outside of it there is no tasks, I don't get it actually, I still don't have a clear vison of it.I edited my question, You can check my whole reducer.

Answer (score 1):

Alright buddy, so there're a few things I want to raise up:

First, you should **always** use your reducers only return new state to Redux, and that's it. You just merge new data that comes from actions, with your old state and return it back. And you can't use `Promise` or `async/await` in there because Redux doesn't and won't support that behavior.

Second, all the business logic **should** be placed in your actions. Data fetching(like in your case), computations and that kind of stuff needs be in actions. And now, you've come to the point where you, most likely, should start using libraries like [`redux-thunk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk) or [`redux-saga`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga) to handle asynchronous operations within your actions. `redux-thunk` is less complicated than `redux-saga`, but `redux-saga` empowers you with a lot of cool features yet it could a bit complicated.

You can go big or start small with these libs, either way, they will force you to move you data fetching into your action. If you want support loading of data, then just dispatch actions that tell `Redux`: "I'm loading data" or "I got an error while loading data" or "I've loaded data". And when that action comes in, update your store, show loader, data or an error if you need. You can take a look on [this](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-redux/) or [that](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions/)  example of using `redux-thunk` for data fetching, there's everything you need to get started with async actions.

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Yes, I will put them in my actions, but I don't think it is my problem I believe, because If I put that code in the action I will get the same thing, my tasks variable won't be filled, it will be empty, meaning I have to wait for my request to get executed fully and then put in the tasks variable, that's what I am looking for..

Comment: And that's exactly what I've written about :) You **don't** need dispatch "data" that hasn't arrived to the client. You just wait when that `Promise` resolves, and **only** then update your store with the data. You will **never** know how long it'll take for the request to come. Check out the example guides at the end of my answer to get better understanding on that. Or just google "async actions react redux" to full point of view why it should be like that :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentiond as in the other answers, I would setup my reducer only to handle state update and the action creator function to fetch data. Here is the minimal starting point if I were to do it. you can use the loading state to display loading spinners or progress bars.

my action creator function with the individual actions:

```
export const GET_TASKS_START = "GET_TASKS";
export const GET_TASKS_SUCCESS = "GET_TASKS_SUCCESS";
export const GET_TASKS_FAILURE = "GET_TASKS_FAILURE";

export const getData = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(GET_TASKS_START);
  axios
    .get("http://localhost:8080/api/taskExecution?&search=&page=1&size=8")
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_TASKS_SUCESS, payload: response.data });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({ type: GET_TASKS_FAILURE, payload: err.response });
    });
};
```

and the reducer would handle the state update as follows:

```
import {
  GET_TASKS_SUCCESS,
  GET_TASKS_FAILURE,
  GET_TASKS_START
} from "./Action.js";

const initialState = {
  tasks: [],
  error: null,
  loading: false
};
export default function tasksReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TASKS_START:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    case GET_TASKS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        tasks: action.payload, 
        error: null
      };
    case GET_TASKS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
  }
}
```

I would suggest console logging and checking the responses  (data and errors ) and modify the two functions accordingly